Excel: sort an array by an ordered list, without custom list
I have a table of post codes, with the amount of shipments being sent to each postcode.
I want to sort this array by post code in a specific order, which I have in a second list.
I do not wish to sort by number of customers, or by numerical order of post codes, but by this specifically ranked list.
I cannot use the custom sort feature, as my list is too long for this feature.

I would like the outcome to look something like the following:

I have office 2016 however for this task I have been trying web based office 365 for use of the sort functions
I have tried the use of SORT and SORTBY but however I format them, I am given the #VALUE! error.
I tried the following formula, but it threw #VALUE!
=SORTBY(A2:B944, D2:E2639)


In your Excel for the web version, try =SORTBY(A2:B944, XMATCH(A2:A944, D2:D2639))

Or use XLOOKUP(A2:a944,d2:d2369,e2:e2369) instead of XMATCH if ranks aren't necessarily in order

BTW, error is due to > The by_array arguments must either be one row high, or one column wide.

You could also utilize an index match function (formulas are assuming you are utilizing tables and not the cell ranges):
=index(Table1[Customer Postcode], match(Table2[RANKINGS], Table1[RANKINGS], 0))

Make your 2nd table in the A column hold static numbers you want to look up, then fill B Column with your Customer Postcode. Then you can make your C Column index match your B column back to table 1.
=index(Table1[Customers], match(Table2[Customer Postcode], Table1[Customer Postcode], 0))


Just giving examples for what others have suggested - it works under web version of Microsoft 365, though the screenshots are from Mac.
As Nathaniel suggested, table approach is 'cleaner' with automatic updates when rows are added or deleted. As Tom suggested, I also prefer to use XLOOKUP to get the ranking.
When ranking is not available for a postal code, with XLOOKUP(,,,0) we give 0 as the ranking, grouping them at the top. We could improve this later.
=SORTBY(
    Postcode_Customers,
    XLOOKUP(
        Postcode_Customers[Postcode],
        Postcode_Ranking[Postcode],
        Postcode_Ranking[Ranking],
        0
    )
)


Update 2024-08-01
Group rows at the bottom when ranking is not specified:
=SORTBY(
Postcode_Customers,
XLOOKUP(
Postcode_Customers[Postcode],
Postcode_Ranking[Postcode],
Postcode_Ranking[Ranking],ROWS(Postcode_Customers)+1))



Using ranges, but accommodating future entries by based on non-empty cells: please adjust the ranges, especially the limit for entries (5,000). As you can see it is not as clean as the table solution.
=SORTBY(
    A5:INDEX(B5:B5000, COUNTA(B5:B5000)),
    XLOOKUP(
        A5:INDEX(A5:A5000, COUNTA(A5:A5000)),
        D5:INDEX(D5:D5000, COUNTA(D5:D5000)),
        E5:INDEX(E5:E5000, COUNTA(E5:E5000)),
        0
    )
)



When I implement this with my table and header names, it just creates a table identical to the first one, not sorted as shown in your image. What could I be doing wrong?
Using web 365

Let me take a look at it.

Did you create both tables? Postcode_Customers: columns Postcode and Customer, Postcode_Ranking: columns Postcode, Ranking. Please let me know if you have.

Most importantly, make sure to have the third parameter for XLOOKUP: Postcode_Ranking[Ranking]; otherwise it will be the same as the original table.

Ive made sure the tables have the correct names and headers. And the formula is as you say, the third parameter is correct. Still replicates first table.

See here: https://prnt.sc/NLaR13XhT9IW

In XLOOKUP(,,,0), could you change 0 to Postcode_Ranking[Ranking],ROWS(Postcode_Customers)+1 so that when postal codes are not found in the ranking table, related Postalcode_Customer's rows are grouped at the bottom instead of at the top.
